# Select2 Multiple: Add several items with one copy+paste

Tags: jquery-select2

I want to add several items in a select2 input field at once.

If I copy+paste "Hawaii Alaska" into the select-multiple [example here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html), then I get:

> No results found

In my case spaces are not allowed in the items.

Is there a way to insert N space sperated items via copy+paste?

Desired result: `(x)Hawaii`   `(x)Alaska`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add token separators in your select2 to identify characters as stopping points for your tags/choices, but unfortunately it bugs on the last copy pasted item

```
//try copy pasting bug,invalid, enhancement, wontfix
//then try bug,invalid, enhancement
//you will see the problem
var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

var placeholder = "select";
$(".mySelect").select2({
    tokenSeparators: [',', ', ', ' '],
    data: data,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    allowClear: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 5
});
```

here is the codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMWQbd

its opened as a bug in github on the library
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3458

Comment: Thank you very much. Works, except the bug you mentioned.

Comment: One question: Your tokenSeparators contains three items. Is this needed? I guess comma and space as single chars should be enough, since ', ' is just a combination of both. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @guettli its probably not needed, I just included all three to make sure i was capturing all combinations