# Select2 v4: select option in multiselect on paste from Excel Sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, jquery-select2

I have scenario where our back-end team will select pincodes from Excel and paste it on pincode multiselect select2 dropdown.

I need to select option which are exactly matched with option dropdown present and remove not match inputs pasted.

I have refer given examples but no luck.
1- [Is it possible to paste a list to a select2 field and match each item in the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197223/is-it-possible-to-paste-a-list-to-a-select2-field-and-match-each-item-in-the-lis)
2- [Select2 Multiple: Add several items with one copy+paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181295/select2-multiple-add-several-items-with-one-copypaste)

Given are the excel copied inputs, all pincode should matched except 401203 and 40008

```
 380001
 401203
 396472
 421301
 382418
 400002
 400008
```

Given is the fiddle.
[jsFiddle for pasting excel inputs](https://jsfiddle.net/WaseemBaraskar/aod3mjvw/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing mix of RnD and tweaking I reached to a solution which perfectly does what we wanted.

I have added `id` on parent div of select2 then bind `paste` event to input.

```
$('#pincode_div').on('paste', function (e) {

    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').trim();
    tokens = pastedData.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g); 

    /* print_console('pastedData', pastedData) */;
    /* print_console('tokens', tokens) */;

    $('#pincode > option').each(function(){
       current_pin.push(this.value);
    });

    found_pin = tokens.filter(value => current_pin.includes(value));

    /* print_console('found_pin', found_pin) */;
    /* print_console('current_pin', current_pin) */;

    //print_console('current input', $('#pincode_div').find('input').val());
    $('.select2-search__field').val('');
    $('#pincode_div').find('input').attr('class')
    $('#pincode').val('');
    $("#pincode").val(found_pin).trigger("change");


});
```

Complete code here [Solved jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WaseemBaraskar/cuk32enq/)

You guys can update my answer or share better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had same need and I found exact solution for this question. Use following HTML and script for multiple select and css given below:

```
<select class="mySelect for" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="">
```

```js
           var placeholder = "Type or paste numbers";
            $(".mySelect").select2({
                tokenSeparators: [',', ', ', ' '],
                data: [],
                placeholder: placeholder,
                allowClear: false,
                maximumSelectionSize: 1,
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col col-3 col-xs-12">
<label>Type or paste numbers</label>
<select class="mySelect for" multiple style="width: 100%;"></select>
</div>
```

[CDN for select2 multiple](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.3/multiple-select.min.js)

[CDN style sheet for select2 multiple](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.3/multiple-select.css)